# How to apply a filter on Angular MultiSelect component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am using the [angular-multi-select](http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/) module in my project.

I would like to add an angular filter to limit the number of results (for example the [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)) filter.

I tried:

```
<div
    multi-select
    input-model="stores | limitTo:10"
    button-label="name"
    item-label="name"
    tick-property="selected"
    selection-mode="single"
    helper-elements=""
> </div>
```

It works but the CPU begins to go 100% and I get many errors in the console

> Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.
>   Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:...

If a use an ng-repeat, I do not have this issue. Do you any idea of what could be wrong?

PS : I am using Angular 1.3.8

Comment: i have the same problem with angular 1.2.26. Did you find a solution?